# How to check if a double value has decimal part if value is in string has multiple dot value

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, decimalformat

I want to display double value in fix specific format for some criteria.

1)  Now the decimal value is $ 1.12.123.45 In that case I want to show $ 1,12,123.45 on my UI.

2)  Now the decimal value is $ 12.123.45 In that case I want to show $ 12,123.45 on my UI.

3)  Now the value is $ 12.123 In that case I want to show $ 12,123 on my UI.

4)  Now the value is $ 12.13 In that case I want to show $ 12.13 on my UI.

**What could be the best way of doing this?**

**- Image 1 showing issue :**

[image: This is Issue show in image :]

**- Image 2 i want output :**

[image: i wantthis output]

Comment: Why is your input data ambiguous?

Comment: because i am also put that data on local database . and also in some android device  automatically show $ 1,23,899 this value to $ 1.23.899 .its device specific issue so i want solution

Comment: Praful, could you please update the description with the issue and output details instead of images. Since the images deployed site may not be available for others like me.

Comment: I think you can try with `java.text.DecimalFormat` where you can define the format as your wish.

Comment: Why are you putting ambiguous data into your database?

Comment: Technically you can do with like value.replace(".",","); but this is not good.You are violating basic concept of computing.
$1.23.899 is never a decimal data. Better change your question detail like you want string manipulation of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

First thing your case is not clear but what you want to achieve here you can do it by this way!

Before setting text to `TextView` simply try to replace your value in your case if you have

```
String value = "$ 7,04,660"
```

call replace function to change your value

```
value = value.replace(".",",");
```

Then use your value to set on `TextView`

Comment: but if my value is decimal  $12,000.45 then above eq give me $12,000,45 result .its wrong